# Flex to CF - URLRequest not posting data

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion

I have a Flex form that gathers information using URLVariables, URLRequest and navigateToURL which sends the data to a ColdFusion page that process the information and generates a PDF.  Everything is working great for 99% of the users but some are reporting the form is coming up blank, which makes me believe something on the client's end is preventing them from passing data.  Has this happened to anyone else when Posting data?  Possibly a firewall or Flash player setting?

Windows -> IE7

Thanks for any light
Shua

Comment: Check with your users the version of the flash player they are using.

Comment: it has to be 9 and up since they are able to run the flex application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check what version of Reader they are using as well. Many of times I've hit my head against the wall trying to figure out a PDF issue only to discover the users aren't at the latest version of Adobe Reader.

I've also seen stuff like this happen when the browser plug-in gets corrupted. The only solution in that case is to uninstall and reinstall Adobe Reader.

Finally make sure that the browsers are setup correctly to not allow caching. Tons of people at my job call my all the time that I didn't up a PDF when it's really their browser cache that is the culprit. Clearing the cache and setting the browser to not cache anything also fixes the problems.

In closing, I'm not too sure that the whole not receiving the URLRequest is the problem here and you should expand your search to other areas.